# Bookdown: Problem of building book with all formats

Tags: r, pdf-generation, bookdown

After clicking "Build Book" button for "All Formats", I got an error message:

***Begin***
Error: LaTeX failed to compile filename.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See filenmae.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In has_crop_tools() :
Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: pdfcrop, ghostcript
-> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.
Execution halted
Error: Failed to run 'render_book' in a new R session.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.

***End***

I followed the procedure at https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging, I was not lucky.

What is the problem?

I have no problem when selecting bookdown::gitbook under the "Build Book" menu.

Comment: First, in my experience, often the cause of the error is revealed earlier in the output. Can you add the previous 30 lines of the output to your question? Also, have you looked at the log file it says to check?

Comment: Thank you @jtbayly.  The problem is solved by looking for error messages earlier in the output.